# What is the simplest method for reading user defaults in Cocoa/OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm porting to **OSX** a simple **unix** application, now using a **NSView** subclass in a **NSWindow**.
There are three color constants (members of this view @interface) which I prefer not having hard-coded, but definable as user-defaults (and loaded at launch) instead. These are:
*a, b* and *c,* all of type **[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed: green: blue: alpha]**.
I'm trying to learn how such values can be made ***read from a user defaults file***, which can be written either manually or by means of the *defaults* system command. Also trying to stay away from digging into Preference Pane Controllers, Color Wells, etc. In **X11** this is very simple. I'm trying to figure out the simplest way of achieving it in **Cocoa**. It's not for an "AppStore" type of app. Is there any working example for such a code or anything similar - couldn't find any on the web? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSUserDefaults, yes...

This is code that I use, I store colors as comma separated rgb values.

```
- (id)getUserPref:(NSString *)aSelector
{
   id returnVal = nil;
   NSString *val = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:aSelector];
   NSArray *vals = [val componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   float rgba[4];
   // brute force validation of string... funky but safe
   if ( [vals count] <= 4 )
   {
      for ( int idx = 0; idx < [vals count]; idx++ )
      {
         val = [vals objectAtIndex:idx];
         val = [val stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"01234567890."] invertedSet]];

         if ( [val length] )
         {
            rgba[idx] = [val floatValue];
            if ( rgba[idx] > 255 || rgba[idx] < 0 )
               break;

            if ( [vals count] == 1 )
            {
               returnVal = [[NSColor colorWithContrastWhite:rgba[0]/255.0 alpha:1.0] retain];
               return returnVal;
            }
            else if ( idx == 2 && [vals count] == 3 )
            {
               returnVal = [[NSColor colorWithContrastRed:rgba[0]/255.0 green:rgba[1]/255.0 blue:rgba[2]/255.0 alpha:1.0] retain];
               return returnVal;            
            }
            else if ( idx == 3 && [vals count] == 4 )
            {
               returnVal = [[NSColor colorWithContrastRed:rgba[0]/255.0 green:rgba[1]/255.0 blue:rgba[2]/255.0 alpha:rgba[3]/255.0] retain];
               return returnVal;            
            }         
         }
      }
   }

   DLogErr(@"bad BGThemeMbox user pref %@", aSelector);

   return nil; // better have a fallback color
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Keith Knauber for your answer, this seems to be a very educative code  snippet, useful to learn from!

Answer (score 1):

Try reading Apple's [Storing NSColor in User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/StoringNSColorInDefaults.html), that along with the documentation for [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) should answer most questions. You'll find you can even bind a color well's value direct to user defaults, so you may not need to steer clear of them at all.

HTH

Comment: I've been already reading _carefully_ through this, @CRD. I understand this is the right way of implementing full color support in an OSX application. To keep it simple, unfortunately, the runtime conditions of my app don't allow for it. That's why I had to go for the _simplest_ solution. Thanks, nevertheless!

Comment: @user3078414: That probably *is* the simplest way of supporting colors in the user defaults. What "runtime conditions" don't allow you to do this?

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment @DarkDust. I fear going off-topic, but FYI, the app is actually "being launched and stopped" by another process through a socket, so by the time it's up it already has to appear as it should and do its work. Therefore the configurable user-defaults must already reside in the obvious place, one way or another. I've tested the reply by Keith Knauber, it's closest to the simplicity I was looking for. Please, don't mind repeating myself in case it wasn't clear enough, the question was **not** about full-color support in an AppStore-grade application. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) class. The documentation has plenty of information and a [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i).

Comment: Thanks @DarkDust. I've already come across the **programming guide** (also titled "implementing an iOS Settings Bundle" in some search engines) which I find a bit inconsistent and rather difficult to follow, but I must have missed the **NSUserDefaults** class reference, including well organized and relevant information.